# Rails Dynamic Database connection based on user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-connection

What I am trying to do is to connect to a database dynamically with rails based on what the user puts in on the web page, I am new to ruby and not sure how to do this, I want support for any common databases but doing it with active record requires you to have the actual database and that is not good, I want to be able to connect to any database without actually having it on my server.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Andrei

Answer (score 1):

You can change the database connection that you want to use by calling `establish_connection` at some point during the flow

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => 'mysql',
:host => 'localhost',
:username => 'name',
:password => 'password',
:database => 'db_name'
)
```

You should even be able to do this in a before filter, if that is what you need to do, or call `establish_connection` on individual models so that they use a different database.

Comment: I know that but I want to be able to connect to 2 databases at the same time to map data from 1 to the other and the databases are not on localhost and do not have all the database clients I want to connect to so I can install all the gems

Comment: I need connectors that do not depend on the db clients being installed so for remote stuff

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - to access the database you have to have a connector to access the database. The database doesn't have to be on localhost, but it does have to be open for a connector to connect to.   Rails code can only access a database through a connector.

Comment: I know but installing the database drivers in rails requires a database client to build the drivers and I am just wondering if there is a way around that ?