# How to compare values from two databases(mysql) in rails-3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-connection

How to compare under given two fields in rails application

- Database1 : report_db,

  - table name : detail,
  - field : v_id
- Database2 : gen_db,

  - table name : vulnerabilities,
  - field : o_id

Database.yml file

- development:

  - adapter: mysql
  - database: gen_db
  - host: localhost
  - username: root
  - password: jeet
- report:

  - adapter: mysql
  - database: report_db
  - host: localhost
  - username: root
  - password: jeet

If any gem is required then plz also mention how to use that gem in rails application

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329693/rails-dynamic-database-connection-based-on-user-input), which gives the option of switching connection dynamically using the establish_connection call and specifying the db connection details.

Its one way to solve your problem.